# Как восстановить windows из папки windows.old?

Tags: windows

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, как восстановить windows 8 из папки windows.old?

Спасибо.

Comment: Каким способом была создана папка Windows.old, и что там есть?

Comment: Она создалась автоматически, после установки windows.

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста,  после такого восстановления винда будет корректно работать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Восстановление Windows.old](http://forum-windows.net/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=461) - rtfm!

Answer (score 1):

Панель управления\Все элементы панели управления\Восстановление файлов Windows 7
Попробуй так

Comment: Так на компьютере винт чист. Есть только оригинальная папка windows.old  Я читал в интернете, что это возможно, меня интересует после этого винда будет корректно работать?